# Python decision logic and loops in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am currently stuck on a coding assignment for Python.  I must make a python dictionary with 10 words, the user should be prompted for a word to search for, the program will search the term and if a match found, display the definition.  I got as far as getting the input, but am stuck on whether to use elif, or for or what.  I need to use a loop, but i'm stuck.  Been on this all day.  Here is the code i have written.

```
# 1. The user should be prompted for a word to search for.
# 2. The program will then search for the term, and if a match is found, display
# the definition.
# 2. You should demonstrate the following concepts: dictionaries, loops, decision logic, user input, and other concepts you feel are necessary.

x = {"Milwaukee": "Bucks", "Oklahoma": "Thunder" , "Portland": "Trailblazers", "Miami": "Heat" , "Boston" : "Celtics", "New York" : "Knicks" ,  "Orlando" : "Magic" , "Houston" : "Rockets" , "Chicago" : "Bulls" , "Indiana" : "Pacers"} 
team = input("enter team:")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
team = input('enter team: ')
if team in x:
    print(x[team])
else:
    print('not found')
```

No loop is needed.

It looks like I'm mistaken -- I thought you were going to find dictionary by using keys, but apparently you're trying to find the City using team. So here goes: before everything, do this:

```
x = {v:k for k, v in x.iteritems()}
```

This will make dictionary `team: city` instead of `city: team` and code above will still work.

Comment: This displays the team name if you enter the city, but the prompt "enter team" suggests you should enter the team name and then display the city that matches, right?

Comment: @entrez ah you're right, can't believe I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Although Rocky's answer is probably the easiest way to do it, if the assignment *requires* you use a loop you can just loop through each item in the dictionary to compare each manually:

```
team = input('enter team name: ')
for item in x:
  if x[item] == team:
    print(item)
```

If you need to display a match whether the user enters a city or a team, you can just check both:

```
team = input('enter team or city name: ')
for item in x:
  if x[item] == team:
    print(item)
  elif item == team:
    print(x[item])
```

Comment: hmm, this didn't do what i was looking for.  When I put in a city, it should loop through to the correct team and then stop.

Comment: If you want it to break the loop once it finds a match, you can put a `break` statement after the `print(x[item])` line (or whatever).